# How to resize a stacklayoutpanel to fit its contents?

Tags: winforms, resize, telerik

I have searched telerik's site for a while now and can not find any mention on how to resize a stacklayoupanel to fit its elements. There are properties that allow resizing to fit its elements; however, these properties are not working for me. I was wondering if there was anyone on here who has used this and can help me out. I have a list view that has listViewVisualItems that do not fit their contents. Rather the contents "leak" out of the visual items below and bleed into the next one.
Here is my custom item class.

```
public class ChargePlotListViewItem : SimpleListViewVisualItem
{
    private LightVisualElement imageElement;
    private LightVisualElement titleElement;
    private LightVisualElement bioElement;
    private StackLayoutPanel stackLayout;

    protected override void CreateChildElements()
    {
        base.CreateChildElements();

        stackLayout = new StackLayoutPanel();
        stackLayout.Orientation = System.Windows.Forms.Orientation.Vertical;
        //stackLayout.AutoSize = true; These do not work
        //stackLayout.AutoSizeMode = RadAutoSizeMode.WrapAroundChildren;

        imageElement = new LightVisualElement();
        imageElement.DrawText = false;
        imageElement.ImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Zoom;
        //imageElement.StretchVertically = false;
        imageElement.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(1, 1, 1, 2);
        imageElement.ShouldHandleMouseInput = false;
        imageElement.NotifyParentOnMouseInput = true;
        imageElement.AutoSizeMode = RadAutoSizeMode.FitToAvailableSize;

        //stackLayout.Children.Add(imageElement);

        titleElement = new LightVisualElement();
        titleElement.TextAlignment = ContentAlignment.TopCenter;
        titleElement.Margin = new Padding(2, 1, 1, 2);
        titleElement.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 8, FontStyle.Italic, GraphicsUnit.Point);
        titleElement.ShouldHandleMouseInput = false;
        titleElement.NotifyParentOnMouseInput = true;
        stackLayout.Children.Add(titleElement);

        bioElement = new LightVisualElement();
        bioElement.TextAlignment = ContentAlignment.BottomLeft;
        bioElement.ShouldHandleMouseInput = false;
        bioElement.NotifyParentOnMouseInput = true;
        bioElement.Margin = new Padding(2, 1, 1, 2);

        bioElement.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 9, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point);
        bioElement.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 114, 118, 125);
        stackLayout.Children.Add(bioElement);

        this.Children.Add(stackLayout);
        //this.stackLayout.Measure(new System.Drawing.SizeF((float)stackLayout.Size.Width, (float)20));

        this.Padding = new Padding(1, 2, 1, 2);
        this.Shape = new RoundRectShape(3);
        this.BorderColor = Color.Black;
        this.BorderGradientStyle = GradientStyles.Solid;
        this.DrawBorder = true;
        this.DrawFill = true;
        this.BackColor = Color.Azure;
        this.GradientStyle = GradientStyles.Solid;
    }


    protected override void SynchronizeProperties()
    {
        base.SynchronizeProperties();

        frmBingMaps.CriminalPlotObject plotObject = this.Data.Value as frmBingMaps.CriminalPlotObject;
        if (plotObject != null)
        {
            try
            {
                this.imageElement.Image = Crime_Information_System.Properties.Resources
                    .bullet_blue;
            }
            catch
            {
            }

            //building the title for the element depending on which names are on record
            StringBuilder NameBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            if (plotObject.Data.FirstName != null | plotObject.Data.FirstName != string.Empty)
                NameBuilder.Append(plotObject.Data.FirstName + " ");

            if (plotObject.Data.LastName != null | plotObject.Data.LastName != string.Empty)
                NameBuilder.Append(plotObject.Data.LastName + " ");
            //NameBuilder.Append(" Charge: " + gangBanger.Incidents[0].Charges[0].ChargeDescription);

            this.titleElement.Text = NameBuilder.ToString();

            StringBuilder BioBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            //this.radDesktopAlert1.ContentText = "<html><b>" + CentralDataStore.AllUsers.Find(P => P.intUserID
            //    == BLAH.SenderID).strFirstName + " " + CentralDataStore.AllUsers.Find(P => P.intUserID ==
            //        BLAH.SenderID).strLastName + "</b><br>" + BLAH.Subject;
            BioBuilder.Append("<html>");
            BioBuilder.Append("<b>Incident ID</b>: " + plotObject.Data.Incidents.Find(
                P => P.IncidentID == plotObject.CaseID).IncidentID.ToString());
            BioBuilder.Append("<br>");
            BioBuilder.Append("<b>Date</b>: " + plotObject.Data.Incidents.Find(
                P => P.IncidentID == plotObject.CaseID).DateOfIncident.ToShortDateString());
            BioBuilder.Append("<br>");
            BioBuilder.Append(plotObject.Data.Incidents.Find(P => P.IncidentID == plotObject
                .CaseID).Description);
            BioBuilder.Append("<br>");
            //BioBuilder.Append("\r\n");
            BioBuilder.Append("<b>Location</b>: ");
            BioBuilder.Append(plotObject.Data.Incidents.Find(P => P.IncidentID ==
                plotObject.CaseID).Location);

            BioBuilder.Append("<br>");
            //BioBuilder.Append("\r\n");
            BioBuilder.Append(string.Format("<b>Charges</b>: "));

            foreach (Charge c in plotObject.Data.Incidents.Find(P => P.IncidentID == plotObject.CaseID
                ).Charges)
            {
                BioBuilder.Append(c.ChargeDescription + ", ");
            }

            BioBuilder.Remove(BioBuilder.Length - 2,2);
            //BioBuilder.Append("
            bioElement.Text = BioBuilder.ToString();

            this.Text = ""; //here to erase the system.crimesysteminformation.plot blah object name

        }
    }

    protected override Type ThemeEffectiveType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(IconListViewVisualItem);
        }
    }

    protected override SizeF MeasureOverride(SizeF availableSize)
    {
        SizeF measuredSize = base.MeasureOverride(availableSize);
        this.stackLayout.Measure(measuredSize);
        return measuredSize;
    }

    protected override SizeF ArrangeOverride(SizeF finalSize)
    {
        base.ArrangeOverride(finalSize);
        this.stackLayout.Arrange(new RectangleF(PointF.Empty, finalSize));
        return finalSize;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To overcome this behavior, please consider allowing the items take their desired size by setting the following property:

```
radListView1.AllowArbitraryItemHeight = true;
```

For your convenience, here is a simplified version of your code in action:

```
void radListView1_VisualItemCreating(object sender, ListViewVisualItemCreatingEventArgs      e)
{
e.VisualItem = new ChargePlotListViewItem();
}

public class ChargePlotListViewItem : SimpleListViewVisualItem
{
private LightVisualElement imageElement;
private LightVisualElement titleElement;
private LightVisualElement bioElement;
private StackLayoutPanel stackLayout;

protected override void CreateChildElements()
{
    base.CreateChildElements();

    stackLayout = new StackLayoutPanel();
    stackLayout.Orientation = System.Windows.Forms.Orientation.Vertical;

    imageElement = new LightVisualElement();
    imageElement.DrawText = false;
    imageElement.ImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Center;
    imageElement.ShouldHandleMouseInput = false;
    imageElement.NotifyParentOnMouseInput = true;

    stackLayout.Children.Add(imageElement);

    titleElement = new LightVisualElement();
    titleElement.TextAlignment = ContentAlignment.TopCenter;
    titleElement.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 8, FontStyle.Italic, GraphicsUnit.Point);
    titleElement.ShouldHandleMouseInput = false;
    titleElement.NotifyParentOnMouseInput = true;
    stackLayout.Children.Add(titleElement);

    bioElement = new LightVisualElement();
    bioElement.TextAlignment = ContentAlignment.BottomLeft;
    bioElement.ShouldHandleMouseInput = false;
    bioElement.NotifyParentOnMouseInput = true;
    bioElement.Margin = new Padding(2, 1, 1, 2);
    bioElement.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 9, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point);
    bioElement.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 114, 118, 125);

    stackLayout.Children.Add(bioElement);

    this.Children.Add(stackLayout);
}

protected override void SynchronizeProperties()
{
    base.SynchronizeProperties();
    DataRowView rowView = this.Data.DataBoundItem as DataRowView;

    imageElement.Image = (Image)rowView.Row["Image"];
    titleElement.Text = rowView.Row["Title"].ToString();
    bioElement.Text = rowView.Row["Bio"].ToString();
    this.Text = ""; //here to erase the system.crimesysteminformation.plot blah object name
}

protected override Type ThemeEffectiveType
{
    get
    {
        return typeof(IconListViewVisualItem);
    }
}
}
```